# Ruby each, different action depending on index, with a pattern?

Tags: ruby, erb

Ok so my title may be confusing. What I want to do is to loop through a collection of models, and for the first two, render a template, for the next four render a different template and next two render the same template as for the first ones, and so on.

Like this:

```
  <% ads.each do |ad| %>
    <% # if it's 1-2, 7-8, 13-14 and so on render as big' %>
      <%= render 'front/home/big_ad', ad: ad %>
    <% # if it's 3-6, 9-12, 15-18 and so on render as small' %>
      <%= render 'front/home/small_ad', ad: ad %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

What would be the cleanest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If your groups would be even long, then you could use `in_groups_of` command, and alternate between them, but with these specifications, the easiest way is this:

```
<% ads.each_with_index do |ad, index| %>
  <% if (index % 6 < 2) %>
    <%= render 'front/home/big_ad', ad: ad %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'front/home/small_ad', ad: ad %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How about [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index)?

Comment: Yes, even better. Mine is a bit more "traditional". I change it now.